# Crop Image Transform in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, crop

I have an image, and using GestureRecognizer to transform.

```
func imagePinView(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    currentEditImage.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentEditImage.transform, sender.scale, sender.scale)
    sender.scale = 1.0
}

func imageRotateView(sender:UIRotationGestureRecognizer){
    let currentTrans = currentEditImage.transform
    currentEditImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTrans, sender.rotation)
    sender.rotation = 0.0
}

func imageDragView(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    self.popUpEditView.bringSubviewToFront(sender.view!)
    let translation = sender.translationInView(self.popUpEditView)
    currentEditImage.center = CGPointMake(currentEditImage.center.x + translation.x, currentEditImage.center.y + translation.y)
    sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.popUpEditView)
}
```

But when I crop image. Its not working. Here is my code:

```
let imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(curImage?.CGImage, rectToCrop)
let croppedImage:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: (curImage?.CGImage)!, scale: 0, orientation: currentEditImage.image!.imageOrientation)
```

Comment: Have you added the gesture recognizers to the imageview? Can you please post more code about the same?

Comment: @RajeevBhatia I'm using a UIView contain imageview and handle gesture recognizers

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Topher Fangio: Yep, I'm using
`    self.currentEditImage.image = currentEditImage.image!.cropImageFromUIView(circleView)
    self.currentEditImage.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`